# having trouble to loading javascript inside ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, dom

I am developing website and I need to change page with ajax. Every single page has different javascript and css. I am doing something wrong with calling javascript when ajax content load. Addition I am successfully call alert box when ajax content load but having trouble with loading original script.
Here is some snippet of my code,
index.html page script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function marmi(){

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //resizeDiv();
    });
    window.onload = function(event) {
        resizeDiv();
    }
    function resizeDiv() {
        vph = jQuery(window).height();
        mamu = (jQuery(window).height() - 277);
        jQuery('#mam').css({'height': mamu + 'px'});

    }
}
</script>
```

this is for ajax 
please note i already tried with jQuery("#about").on("click", function(){ .. } this but haven't successful

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    jQuery("#about").click(function(){
        marmi();
    });
    jQuery('#about').trigger('click');
    jQuery("#architecture").click(function(){
        function myFunction(){
            jQuery.globalEval(alert("Hello\nContact"))
        }
        myFunction();
    });
</script>
```

here is main ajax script where url and ajax content load

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = jQuery('.aj_me').each(function() {
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        if (hash == href.substr(0, href.length - 5)) {
            var toLoad = hash + '.html #ajax';
            jQuery('#ajax').load(toLoad)
        }
    });
    jQuery('a.aj_me').click(function() {
        var toLoad = jQuery(this).attr('href') + ' #ajax';
        jQuery('#ajax').hide('normal', loadContent);
        window.location.hash = jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(0, jQuery(this).attr('href').length - 5);

        function loadContent() {
            jQuery('#ajax').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent())
        }

        function showNewContent() {
            jQuery('#ajax').show('normal');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I am loading ajax content in this div

```
<div id="ajax">

</div>
```

all individual pages loading properly without ajax. please someone help to identify problem

thankx
updated
modified ajax script

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = jQuery('.aj_me').each(function() {
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        console.log("href is:",href);
        if (hash == href.substr(0, href.length - 5)) {
            var toLoad = hash + '.html #ajax';
            console.log("Going to load url:",toLoad);
            jQuery('#ajax').load(toLoad)
        }
    });

    jQuery('a.aj_me').click(function() {
        var toLoad = jQuery(this).attr('href') + ' #ajax';
        jQuery('#ajax').hide('normal', loadContent);
        window.location.hash = jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(0, jQuery(this).attr('href').length - 5);

        function loadContent() {
            jQuery('#ajax').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent)
        }

        function showNewContent() {
            jQuery('#ajax').show('normal');
            marmi();
        }
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

console output

```
href is: index.html 
href is: about.html 
href is: contact.html 
href is: index.html 
href is: about.html 
href is: contact.html
```

modified index.html page script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function successCallback() {
  function marmi(){

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        resizeDiv();
    });
    window.onload = function(event) {
        resizeDiv();
    }
    function resizeDiv() {
        vph = jQuery(window).height();
        mamu = (jQuery(window).height() - 277);
        jQuery('#mam').css({'height': mamu + 'px'});

    }
}
}

function completeCallback() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        resizeDiv();
    });
    window.onload = function(event) {
        resizeDiv();
    }
    function resizeDiv() {
        vph = jQuery(window).height();
        mamu = (jQuery(window).height() - 277);
        jQuery('#mam').css({'height': mamu + 'px'});

    }
    alert('comleted');
}

function errorCallback() {
    alert('error');
}

jQuery.ajax({
    url:"index.html",
    success:successCallback,
    complete:completeCallback,
    error:errorCallback

});
</script>
```

Comment: You should provide a **minimum** complete example of what fails and what you were expecting, the above question as it stands now, makes it hard to identify what you're trying to fix.

Comment: my script is conflict therefore i am using jQuery instead of $ i know but i am unable to provide live link as per my company policy

Comment: Ahh, fair enough @simpleclick

Comment: I see one mistake.  This `jQuery('#ajax').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent())` should be this: `jQuery('#ajax').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 unfortunately I modified with this but it doesn't work for me so it should be different error

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that that issue was your main problem, but it was something that needed fixing.

Comment: if (hash == href.substr(0, href.length - 5)) is never true so it won't try to load anything. Can you log hash as well?  console.log("href is:",href);console.log("hash is:",hash);

Comment: @HMR after console.log("hash is:",hash); adding console output is href is: about.html 
hash is:  contact.html 
hash is:

Comment: @simpleclick your if statement is never true: if (hash == href.substr(0, href.length - 5))  According to you the output console.log("Going to load url:",toLoad); does not show so the line jQuery('#ajax').load(toLoad) is never executed. It's not an ajax problem it's just that because the if statement is never true the ajax bit is never executed.

Comment: @HMR i fix that bug i am getting hash value but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Mybe you could delete this question and post a new one with some logs indicating what does and doesn't work. So at the moment it is logging the "going to load" and showing what it is going to load (if so why not update your question). Does it show xhr request in Firebug windows (network tab and console tab usually shows xhr requests)

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's in the following part of your code, could you add the suggested console.logs and check the console for xhr activity? You can use Firefox with the firebug plugin or Chrome. Press F12 to see the console

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = jQuery('.aj_me').each(function() {
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        console.log("href is:",href);
        if (hash == href.substr(0, href.length - 5)) {
            var toLoad = hash + '.html #ajax';
            console.log("Going to load url:",toLoad);
            jQuery('#ajax').load(toLoad)
        }
    });
```

Comment: just modified my ajax script as u mention and added console output above it seems like browser only getting html content nothing else

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at jQuery's source (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js) and you take a look at the load function, you'll see that when you specify a selector to pull from the document it parses the selector's content using **$.parseHTML()**

```
 self.html( selector ?

    // If a selector was specified, locate the right elements in a dummy div
    // Exclude scripts to avoid IE 'Permission Denied' errors
    jQuery("<div>").append( jQuery.parseHTML( responseText ) ).find( selector ) :
```

$.parseHTML blocks scripts by default, but this can be overridden by passing a "true" as your second argument to the parseHTML function.

Long story short... If you want to run scripts, you can roll your own custom ajax function in place of using load.

```
var toLoad = '#ajax';

$.ajax({
    url: yourURL,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
       var content = $('<div>').append($.parseHTML(response), true).find(toLoad);
       $('#ajax').html(content[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind, if you do this you can run into permission errors in IE (as specified in the comments copied from the jQuery source above).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to take a look at the JQuery AJAX documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

If you want have Javascript code that runs after your AJAX call successfully completes, put that code in the success section below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/login/process',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) 
    {
        // Javascript to run
    }
});
```

Comment: He's using `.load()` which has it's own completion function.  I don't see where this is a problem for the OP?

Comment: I think he could benefit from refactoring his code and using the $ notation for JQuery. If it was more readable it might help the community to better understand his problem and provide a solution.

Comment: I cant use $ if I use than my script conflict and it piss me off

Comment: unfortunately none when I use alert function inside success i can get alert u may check code i just upload above

Comment: If you're using Google Chrome or FireFox you can put  console.log('hello'); to log messages to the output window.

Maybe take a look at the page you're calling too to make sure it isn't failing there? You can try Fiddler for debugging that.

Comment: @viscro i am getting console.log output i already uploaded above but nothing else

Comment: Oh, I missed that. :) Maybe try creating a new page that has less complexity and just try narrowing down the problem until you can pinpoint a specific error. Without an error it is hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: I am using simple resize div height script in about.html, and this script is working when I reload inner page (localhost/html/index.html#about.html) but it doesn't work when ajax content load. So I am just wondering it is problem with my resize script because I am using document.ready() and window.onload function??? u may check resize div script above

Comment: @simpleclick - If you're expecting script blocks in the ajax loaded code to run, they will not run if using the #xxx suffix with `.load()`.  See the "Script Execution" section of the [jQuery `.load()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: It could be... I have no idea without running the code myself. You don't get any errors in your Javascript error console in the browser? Maybe start by commenting out the resize and div height code out and see if makes a difference for you? :)

Comment: @jfriend00 none of my script using $('#b').load('article.html #target'); this kind of content, i am using like $('#b').load('article.html); this

Comment: @viscro, I am having difficulty with this jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
   cache: false
  });

  jQuery("#about").on("click", function(){
   marmi();
  });
  jQuery('#about').trigger('click'); after adding jQuery.ajax(); function I am not sure how to call this function on when i am sending ajax request

Comment: @simpleclick - that's not true, you are using `#ajax` on your URLs.  Look at these lines of code: `var toLoad = hash + '.html #ajax';` followed by `jQuery('#ajax').load(toLoad)`

Comment: oh yeah thanks for pointing me error, is there any alternative available